# How to find K-means total number of iterations in sklearn python?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

how to find out the number of iterations in k-means using python scikit-learn?

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
#from nltk.cluster import KMeansClusterer, euclidean_distance
dataset =pd.read_csv('data_akhir/sampel_akhir.csv')
X = dataset
 
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
wcss = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, init = 'k-means++', random_state=42)
    kmeans.fit(X)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
 
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 5, init = 'k-means++', random_state=42)
y_kmeans = kmeans.fit_predict(X)
file=open('data_akhir/hasil5.csv','a')
tulis=csv.writer(file,delimiter='\n',lineterminator='\n')
tulis.writerows([y_kmeans])
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `kmeans.n_iter_`to get number of iterations run.
See [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html).

Comment: but, when I use max_iter 5 the result is 10

Comment: I tried some example and don't faced such a case. Can you provide a reproducible example?